# Building Java Library and catching exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I am building my first Java library. The code uses lots of IO methods, so as you can imagine there are lots of exceptions to be caught. But I'm wondering, should I throw the exceptions? I mean surely it's the application writer's job to catch the exceptions. Because even if I catch them, I don't really know what the application would like to do in the event of this occurrence.

Should I throw IOExceptions etc, or should I catch them in the library code?

Comment: You *must* re-throws exceptions - [Best Practice: Catching and re-throwing Java Exceptions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21386753)

Comment: That is a strong must. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557066/how-to-handle-exceptions-when-writing-a-library-not-an-application-java?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle exceptions **only if you can** - i.e. if your library has sufficient knowledge on how the exception should be dealt with.

Here's an example when you **should** handle an exception:

- Library receives request from user
- Library tries to read a configuration file
- There is a IOException because the config file is not found
- Library catches the exception and falls back to using a default configuration (perhaps issuing a warning to the user that there is no configuration file)

Here's an example where you **should not** handle an exception

- Library receives a request from the user
- The processing request fails when trying to parse an integer from a String in the request (gets a NumberFormatException)
- Library cannot handle the exception - assuming a default value (e.g. 0) would be dangerous
- Exception is thrown back to the user for them to handle

If you are going to throw an exception to the user, it is often good practice to **catch and re-throw** the exception - this enables you to wrap it in your own custom exception class and potentially add extra messages / details etc.

In general remember that if you want to write a good software component then it should have [fail-fast behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast). If in doubt, you should fail and let the user know (via an exception) rather than attempt to continue on an unsound basis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a common practice. But be sure you to throw as much as possible all of the approriate exceptions that a particular methods may occur upon runtime. In addition to that, according to [Effective Java - Second Edition](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf) Item 62 - "Document all exceptions thrown by each method". You may never know when you might re-use or include that library your working on in the next projects to come.

> For more details, read Chapter 9 of the book.